# What kind of algorithm is used in Paper.io 2 game?

Tags: algorithm, android-studio, bots, game-physics

I have watched paper.io 2 game play and i am creating my own game which resembles the bots of this game.
What algorithm is being used for bots physics in this game or he has set his own algorithm for bots?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: so your saying creating your own algorithm which suits your game is better but are there any algorithm that can be taken as good example for this case.